# How to remove the '.' after the organization's name as an author? (apacitex)

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

How to remove the '.' after the organization's name as an author, i.e. 'NTIA (2010)' instead of 'NTIA. (2010), but keeping the dot when referencing real people, e.g., Nassri, A. (2015)?

I am using the following two reference entries with `apacitex`:

```
@MISC{haradopters:2015,
  author = {Nassri, Ahmad},
  title = {{HAR} Resources: {A} community curated list of resources, tools, projects and applications that support {HTTP Archive (HAR)}.},
  year = {2015},
  howpublished={[Github]},
  url={https://github.com/ahmadnassri/har},
  urldate={28 June 2015}
} 

@MISC{ntia:2010,
  author = {{NTIA}},
  title = {Commercial Data Privacy and Innovation in the Internet Economy: {A} Dynamic Policy Framework.},
  howpublished={{IPTF Privacy Green Paper}},
    year = {2010},
  publisher={{National Telecommunications and Information Administration (NTIA)}},
  address={Washington, DC}
}
```

which give me the following bibliographic entries

> ```
> Nassri, A. (2015). HAR resources: A community curated list of re-
>    sources, tools, projects and applications that support HTTP Archive
>    (HAR). [Github]. Retrieved 28 June 2015, from https://
>    github.com/ahmadnassri/har
> NTIA. (2010). Commercial data privacy and innovation in the internet
>    economy: A dynamic policy framework. IPTF Privacy Green Paper.
>    Washington, DC: National Telecommunications and Informa-
>    tion Administration (NTIA).
> ```

However, I would like to see:

> ```
> Nassri, A. (2015). HAR resources: A community curated list of re-
>     sources, tools, projects and applications that support HTTP Archive
>     (HAR). [Github]. Retrieved 28 June 2015, from https://
>     github.com/ahmadnassri/har
> NTIA (2010). Commercial data privacy and innovation in the internet
>     economy: A dynamic policy framework. IPTF Privacy Green Paper.
>     Washington, DC: National Telecommunications and Informa-
>     tion Administration (NTIA).
> ```

The MWE is as follows (pre-requisites are (1) apacite and (2) classicthesis, http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/classicthesis.zip)

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\PassOptionsToPackage{parts}{classicthesis}                                     
\PassOptionsToPackage{natbibapa,index}{apacite}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{classicthesis} 

\begin{document}

\citep{haradopters:2015}
\citep{ntia:2010}

\bibliographystyle{apacitex}
\bibliography{References} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you give us a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)? It is quite tiresome having to guess all the settings and packages you use in your document.

Comment: I have re-tagged your question as you mention `apacite` multiple times, but `biblatex` only in the tags.

Comment: @moewe, tnx. I will provide a MWE.

Comment: Did you get around to creating a MWE or did the problem go away on its own?

Comment: @moewe, apologies for not getting back sooner on the MWE. I have not been able to solve the problem. Help is still welcome.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot run your example because I can neither find `myapacitex.bst` on my machine nor anywhere on the internet. Is that a custom styles?

Comment: Never mind, it is the same with `apacitex.bst`, but the code is a bit too overwhelming for me at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*update*: at bottom, variant to address an issue raised in comments. (for a few minutes the code was completely wrong: next time I will check the output before posting `;-)`...)

Can you try this with your big document:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\PassOptionsToPackage{parts}{classicthesis}                                     
\PassOptionsToPackage{natbibapa,index}{apacite}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{classicthesis} 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\APACrefauthstyle}{\rvaneijk@refauthstyle}%
\def\rvaneijk@refauthstyle #1.%
    {\rvaneijk@refauthstyle@a #1,,\@@rvaneijk {#1}}%
\def\rvaneijk@refauthstyle@a  #1,#2,#3\@@rvaneijk #4%
    {\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax {#4}\else {#4}.\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\citep{haradopters:2015}
\citep{ntia:2010}

\bibliographystyle{apacitex}
\bibliography{References} 

\end{document}
```

It appears that `apacite` always puts a dot, but the code above tests if the author name contains a comma. If it doesn't contain a comma, the dot is removed.

Not being familiar with `apacite` nor with `bibtex` any better, I can not vouch this is robust.

Here is the result:

[image]

This used file `References.bib`:

```
@MISC{haradopters:2015,
  author = {Nassri, Ahmad},
  title = {{HAR} Resources: {A} community curated list of resources, tools, projects and applications that support {HTTP Archive (HAR)}.},
  year = {2015},
  howpublished={[Github]},
  url={https://github.com/ahmadnassri/har},
  urldate={28 June 2015}
} 

@MISC{ntia:2010,
  author = {{NTIA}},
  title = {Commercial Data Privacy and Innovation in the Internet Economy: {A} Dynamic Policy Framework.},
  howpublished={{IPTF Privacy Green Paper}},
    year = {2010},
  publisher={{National Telecommunications and Information Administration (NTIA)}},
  address={Washington, DC}
}
```

---

Due to my unfamiliarity with `biblatex` I had somewhat foolishly assumed on the basis of the sole two bibliographic datas above that a `dot` would always be present. But clearly at some point in creation of `bbl` file, a mechanism makes sure not to add a final dot to the author entry if one is already present. If this `dot` was between braces it could not be seen by the macro `\rvaneijk@refauthstyle` above.

Thus, here is an alternative which is supposed to fix that issue. Hopefully it doesn't break something else.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\PassOptionsToPackage{parts}{classicthesis}                                     
\PassOptionsToPackage{natbibapa,index}{apacite}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{classicthesis} 

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\APACrefauthstyle}{\rvaneijk@refauthstyle}%

\catcode`Z 3
\def\rvaneijk@refauthstyle #1\AX
% first check if a dot is present at the end
% this dot will possibly arise after brace stripping of #1
% I assume here the \AX is always present as in my three examples...
   {\rvaneijk@refauthstyle@aa #1Z.Z.X\@@rvaneijk #1\AX}%
\def\rvaneijk@refauthstyle@aa #1.Z.#2#3\@@rvaneijk
% if a dot is detected (it should always be, either in the original 
% record, or inserted by biblatex)
% we then apply our macro which checks if the entry contains a comma.
% if a comma is found, the dot will be left. If no comma is found,  
% the dot is gobbled and not reinserted. As I think the dot is
% always found, I am not too worried by the possible brace-stripping 
% of #1 above, because braces are added below anyhow in all cases.
   {\ifx Z#2\expandafter\rvaneijk@refauthstyle@a\fi}%
\catcode`Z 11
\def\rvaneijk@refauthstyle@a #1.%
    {\rvaneijk@refauthstyle@b #1,,\@@rvaneijk {#1}}%
\def\rvaneijk@refauthstyle@b  #1,#2,#3\@@rvaneijk #4%
    {\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax {#4}\else {#4}.\fi}%  
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\citep{haradopters:2015}
\citep{ntia:2010}
\citep{foo:2013}

\bibliographystyle{apacitex}

\bibliography{References} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

This was done with extra record

```
@MISC{foo:2013,
  author = {{Company, Inc.}},
  title = {Foolish company.},
  howpublished={{Homemade}},
    year = {2013},
  publisher={{Myself}},
  address={Nowhereland}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. The pdf gets generated but produces an error that was not there before. I think is has to do with some errors in the large Reference.bib file which bibtex complains about and previously didn't. I will try to track down what it is and report back.

Comment: All bibtex warnings are cleaned up now. The problem seems to be in pdftex. My workaround is to comment the changes when drafting, and uncomment the final version.

Comment: Ideally the changes should not cause errors or warnings: have you examined the `log` file and check if the first error (usually on a line starting with an `!`) mentions something like the `\APACrefauthstyle` or the `\rvaneijk@...` macros from my proposal ? if yes, it would be nice to see that error message; you could try by dichotomy to build a mwe showing the problem but this can take time (this needs copying the big `References.bib` file in order to cut it to smaller and smaller pieces by dichotomy).

Comment: SOLVED: I added '\errorcontextlines 10000' to the pre-amble to get some clues. Fortunately it did. One off the bib entries was slightly odd, i.e. 'author = {{Company, Inc.}}'. I Changed it to 'author = {{Company}}' to prevent your macro from breaking. The log showed: <to be read again> 
                   \endgroup 
\end ...use {@end@#1@hook}\csname end#1\endcsname 
                                                  \@checkend {#1}\expandafte...
<argument> ...ologies, Inc.}}\end {APACrefauthors}
                                                  \unskip \

Comment: Sorry that you have spent time about that. The problem arose from the fact that the dot in `{{Company, Inc.}}` is detected by `biblatex`, hence no extra dot is added, and my delimited macro caused the error (because the dot in `{Company, Inc.}` is hidden from view). I have added a new method which should work with the original unmodified `References.bib` file.