# Reference list: Suppressing dots after company names (apacite)

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, apa-style

When referencing companies, I would like to remove the dot after the name of the company, but in the same document keep the dot when referencing author names. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\BRetrievedFrom}{Verfügbar unter\ }}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@misc{eprime,
    title = {E-Prime 2 ({Version} 2.0.10.242)},
    author = {{Psychology Software Tools}},
    year = {2012},
    type = {\bibcomputersoftware},
    url = {https://www.pstnet.com/eprime.cfm}}

@misc{matlab,
    title = {MATLAB ({Version} 8.1.0.604, R2013a)},
    author = {{MathWorks Inc.}},
    year = {2013},
    type = {\bibcomputersoftware},
    url = {http://mathworks.com/downloads/}}

@book{McDonald1999,
    author = {McDonald, Roderick P.},
    title = {Test theory: A unified treatment},
    publisher = {Erlbaum},
    address = {Mahwah, NJ},
    year = {1999}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
Eprime was used \citep{eprime}.\\
MATLAB was used \citep{matlab}.\\
\citet{McDonald1999} showed that \ldots
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

With this MWE I get the following reference list

[image: Image of the reference list using the code in the MWE]

How do I remove the dot after "Psychology Software Tools. (2012)."? It should look like this: "Psychology Software Tools (2012)."

I have seen a similar question ([How to remove the '.' after the organization's name as an author? (apacitex)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261140/how-to-remove-the-after-the-organizations-name-as-an-author-apacitex)), but the code snippet that solved that problem

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\APACrefauthstyle}{\rvaneijk@refauthstyle}%
\def\rvaneijk@refauthstyle #1.%
    {\rvaneijk@refauthstyle@a #1,,\@@rvaneijk {#1}}%
\def\rvaneijk@refauthstyle@a  #1,#2,#3\@@rvaneijk #4%
    {\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax {#4}\else {#4}.\fi}
\makeatother
```

does return an error in my MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that modifying the APA formatting rules is a good idea. (For one, it may make your paper unpublishable in a journal that requires use of the APA6 guidlines.) However, if you think you can get away with such a modification, you could proceed as follows:

- Locate the file `apacite.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `apacite-mod.bst`.
- Open the file `apacite-mod.bst` in a text editor. (The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.)
- Locate the function `authors.reflist.apa6`. (In my copy of the file, this function starts on line 2926.)
- In this function, locate the following lines of code:

  ```
    numnames  #1  =
      { dot
          { add.period$ }
          'skip$
        if$
  ```

  Change them to

  ```
    numnames  #1  =
      {
  ```
- Save the file `apacite-mod.bst`, either to the director that contains your main tex file or to a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter method, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution.
- In the main tex file, change the instruction `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` to `\bibliographystyle{apacite-mod}`, and rerun LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Two caveats are in order. First, the proposed solution won't work correctly if an entry has two (or more) corporate authors. Second, the proposed solution assumes that there are no single-name authors (i.e., a name without a separate first-name component) in your bibliography; if you have works by Cher, Bono, or Madonna in your bibliography, don't be surprised that there's no "dot" at the ends of their names...

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{Test.bib}
@misc{eprime,
    title = {E-Prime 2 ({Version} 2.0.10.242)},
    author = {{Psychology Software Tools}},
    year = {2012},
    type = {\bibcomputersoftware},
    url = {https://www.pstnet.com/eprime.cfm},
}
@misc{matlab,
    title = {MATLAB ({Version} 8.1.0.604, R2013a)},
    author = {{MathWorks Inc.}},
    year = {2013},
    type = {\bibcomputersoftware},
    url = {http://mathworks.com/downloads/},
}
@book{McDonald1999,
    author = {McDonald, Roderick P.},
    title = {Test theory: A unified treatment},
    publisher = {Erlbaum},
    address = {Mahwah, NJ},
    year = {1999}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[hyphens,spaces,obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite-mod}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\BRetrievedFrom}{Verfügbar unter\ }}

\begin{document}
\citep{eprime}

\citep{matlab}

\citet{McDonald1999} \dots

\bibliography{Test}
\end{document}
```